# How to catch @rollup/plugin-typescript errors

Tags: typescript, rollup, rollupjs

I use api `rollup.watch(options)` to build typescript.

By default `@rollup/plugin-typescript` will print an error message in the console if there is a compile error, but no file name and line number is printed, and `watcher.on('event')` does not trigger the error event.

I found that the option `noEmitOnError: true` triggers the error event in `watcher.on('event')`, but only the first time, the second time it throws an error and exit.

```js
import rollupTypescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

let options: rollup.RollupWatchOptions = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        rollupTypescript({
            noEmitOnError: true,
            tsconfig: path.join(__dirname, `tsconfig.json`),
        }),
    ],
};

let watcher = rollup.watch(options);

watcher.on('event', async (evt) => {
    if (evt.code === 'ERROR') {
        console.log(evt);
    }
});
```

version

- rollup: 2.46.0
- @rollup/plugin-typescript: 8.2.1

How do I safely catch the error?

Comment: Poor man's option could be adding `console.log('***', warning.loc);` to `function diagnosticToWarning` line circa 176 after `warning.loc = {...};` in `node_modules/@rollup/plugin-typescript/dist/index.js`. It will be rewritten with each modules install and is definitely not a valid solution, but can at least help a little bit. If I have time, I will have a look into more stable solution.